# Different notions of geodesics

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a (without boundary and not necessarly complete) Riemannian manifold.

A map $c\colon [a,b]\rightarrow M$ is called **geodesic of type A** iff $c$ is piecewise smooth, parametrized proportional to arclength and for all $t\in[a,b]$ there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that $L(c|_{[t-\epsilon,t+\epsilon]})=d(c(t-\epsilon),c(t+\epsilon))$. ($L$ is the lengthfunctional and $d$ the distance in $M$.)

A map $c\colon [a,b]\rightarrow M$ is called **geodesic of type B** iff $c$ is smooth and is autoparallel with respect to the levi-civita-connection of $M$.

**Are those two notions always to 100% equivalent? If not, why and under which precondition and/or changes are they?**

Edit: JasonDeVito suggested a positive answer by using the first variation formula. An additional question of mine is now:

Is there a proof without using the first the variation formula and Jacobi fields just by using techniques like Riemann normal coordinates and the expobential function?

Comment: Do you allow manifolds with boundary?

Comment: No, without boundary.

Comment: Whatever the implications (or lack thereof), I suspect that the missing link is the variational definition of geodesic (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic#Riemannian_geometry). Observe, in particular, that being autoparallel w.r.t. the Levi-Civita connection is precisely satisfying the Euler--Lagrange equations for the Energy functional on curves.

Comment: I don't have time to write up a complete answer, but the thing to google search is "first variation formula".  The short answer - yes, they are they same.

Comment: I edited my answer by inserting an additional question regarding your answer.